# CSS Table Row border color with border-collapse

Tags: jquery, css, row, border, css-tables

I've seen several posts here on the subject, and I've read the W3C spec on border style conflict-resolution (and admit, I don't fully get it), and I'm not sure how to achieve what I want.

On row hover, I want to change the color of the border around the row. I have surmised the best cross-browser way to do it is change the td border colors in that row. However, I can't seem to execute it in a way where the row's top border also changes.

Here's my CSS:

```
#dataGrid table {
border: 1px solid #cacac8; /* I've tried it with and without this border setting */
table-layout: fixed;
border-collapse: collapse;
}

#dataGrid td {
    border: 1px solid #cacac8;
    padding: 8px 11px 7px 11px;
    text-align: left;
}

#dataGrid .cellHovered {
    border-top: 1px solid #425474;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #425474;
}

#dataGrid .cellFirstHovered {border-left: 1px solid #425474;}
#dataGrid .cellLastHovered {border-right: 1px solid #425474;}
```

and my JQuery:

```
$('div#dataGrid tr.dataRow').hover(
        function () {
            $(this).children('td').addClass('cellHovered');
            $(this).children('td:first').addClass('cellFirstHovered');
            $(this).children('td:last').addClass('cellLastHovered');
        },
        function() {
            $(this).children('td').removeClass('cellHovered');
            $(this).children('td:first').removeClass('cellFirstHovered');
            $(this).children('td:last').removeClass('cellLastHovered');
    });
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Firstly, you might be better off not using jQuery and instead using pure CSS:

```
#datagrid tr.datarow:hover td {
    border: whatever;
}
```

Next, since you're using 1px borders, try this trick:

```
#datagrid tr.datarow:hover td {
    border-style: double;
}
```

Since `double` is "more distinct" then `solid`, its colour takes precedence over cells around it, and looks identical to `solid` anyway ;)

Comment: I'll be a sunnuva-gun. Works well. Thanks very much. Happen to know if it's good for IE 7?

Comment: As far as I can tell, yes it works fine. At least, it works in IE9 in IE7 mode (which seems fairly reliable in my experience). IE6, however, won't like it, but that's okay :p

Comment: Hmm...this puts borders around each cell in the row. If I leave out the td with the CSS hover, and just put a border around the row, does that work with IE 7? (Or any flavor of IE, for that matter.

Comment: Not sure, but you can use `:first-child` and `:last-child` selectors on the `td`s to do the side borders, then have the rest of them only do top and bottom. That'd work.

Comment: Hehehe... what a trick! I've been looking for a solution for a long time. This one did the TRICK with a single shot.