# jQuery / CSS: Changing border color not working properly with border-collapse

Tags: jquery, css, hover, mouseover

I am new to CSS and jQuery and hope someone can help me with this.

I have a large HTML table that is created dynamically. 
Within this table I just **want to highlight the borders of a td when hovering over it**.

First I tried to use `:hover` in CSS for this but I couldn't find a way to realise this in CSS at all. It seems it doesn't work in this case ?

I then tried to use JS in the document ready function which does apply border colors but only to two of the four border sides which I guess is caused by CSS' `border-collapse:collapse;`. 
It works without the border-collapse but I do need this as double borders or `border-spacing: 0;` take too much space in this large table and make the tds appear smaller.

**Note:** This only refers to tds that contain a div as this way I would like to show which of them are editable.

Can someone tell me how I can work around this or what other options there are ?

**My JS:**

```
$(document).on({
    mouseenter: function(){
        $(this).parent().css('border-color', 'blue');
    },
    mouseleave: function(){
        $(this).parent().css('border-color', '');
    }
}, 'div.editable');
```

**My CSS (relevant part only):**

```
#tblCalendar, #tblCalendar th, #tblCalendar td {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin: 0;
}
```

**My HTML (example td):**

```
...<td><div contenteditable="true" class="editable"></div></td>...
```

Many thanks in advance, 
Mike

Comment: I think the below link helps you to 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942212/css-table-row-border-color-with-border-collapse/7942229#7942229

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on @RickHitchcock's answer, you can also do this using the css `::before` pseudo element. But you have to set `z-index: -1px` so it will allow you to edit the `contenteditable` areas.

```
#tblCalendar th:hover::before, 
#tblCalendar td:hover::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px; left: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```css
#tblCalendar, #tblCalendar th, #tblCalendar td {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}
#tblCalendar th:hover::before, 
#tblCalendar td:hover::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px; left: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tblCalendar">
  <tr>
    <td><div contenteditable="true" class="editable">This is a test</div></td>
    <td><div contenteditable="true" class="editable">This is a test</div></td>
    <td><div contenteditable="true" class="editable">This is a test</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div contenteditable="true" class="editable">This is a test</div></td>
    <td><div contenteditable="true" class="editable">This is a test</div></td>
    <td><div contenteditable="true" class="editable">This is a test</div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot and sorry for the late response ! This works great and is easy to implement - perfect fix ! :)

Answer (score 3):

`border-collapse` makes it difficult to do this using `border`, but you could use `outline` instead like this:

```js
$(document).on({
  mouseenter: function() {
    $(this).parent().css('outline', '1px solid blue');
  },
  mouseleave: function(){
    $(this).parent().css('outline', '');
  }
}, 'div.editable');
```

```css
#tblCalendar, #tblCalendar th, #tblCalendar td {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tblCalendar">
  <tr>
    <td><div contenteditable="true" class="editable">This is editable</div></td>
    <td><div contenteditable="true" class="editable">This is editable</div></td>
    <td>Not editable</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Not editable</td>
    <td><div contenteditable="true" class="editable">This is editable</div></td>
    <td><div contenteditable="true" class="editable">This is editable</div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for this as well and sorry for the late response ! It works in your code snippet but for some reason this doesn't work in my code, perhaps due to the position ?